# Python-Arduino Web

Tags: python-2.7, sensors, arduino-uno, web.py

So I am going off of the book called 'Python Programming for Arduino', and I am currently having trouble working the web ex 2 in the book. I know that github has the code at this link: https://github.com/Python-programming-Arduino/ppfa-code/tree/master/Chapter%2008/Exercise%202%20-%20Webpy%20Serial

However, I am still experiencing issues with it. I know python 2.7 is discontinued but I think I have to keep everything in python 2.7 because that is what the book is using.

Error that occurs whenever I run the python code:

raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Code being used:

```
import web
from web import form
import serial


port = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=1)

render = web.template.render('templates')

urls = (
    '/', 'index')


class index:
    submit_form = form.Form(
        form.Textbox('Temperature', description='Temperature'),
        form.Button('submit', type="submit", description='submit')
    )

    def GET(self):
        f = self.submit_form()
        f.validates()
        line = port.readline()
        if line:
            data = float(line)
            humidity = relativeHumidity(line, 25)
            return render.base(f, humidity)
        else:
            return render.base(f, "Not valid data")

    def POST(self):
        f = self.submit_form()
        f.validates()
        temperature = f['Temperature'].value
        line = port.readline()
        if line:
            data = float(line)
            humidity = relativeHumidity(line, float(temperature))
            return render.base(f, humidity)
        else:
            return render.base(f, "Not valid data")


def relativeHumidity(data, temperature):
    volt = float(data) / 1024 * 5.0
    sensorRH = 161.0 * volt / 5.0 - 25.0
    trueRH = sensorRH / (1.0546 - 0.0026 * temperature)
    return trueRH


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I have tried creating the templates folder in the same folder that runs my python program and the only thing I know for sure that works is the Arduino code because the serial monitor works fine.

Any help is appreciated and I tried to be as thorough in my experience so I can get better help than to make sure my port is connected and updated because that has already been done.

Update

I have verified that I am communicating with the correct port but now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Edgar Castillo/PycharmProjects/WebCH8/webEx2.py", line 51, in <module>
    if __name__() == "__main__":
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have tinkered around with the code and cannot remember if I made any incredibly notable changes but here is the code I am running for the error above.

```
import web
from web import form
import serial

port = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=1)


render = web.template.render('templates')

urls = (
    '/', 'index')


class index:
    submit_form = form.Form(
        form.Textbox('Temperature', description='Temperature'),
        form.Button('submit', type="submit", description='submit')
    )

    def GET(self):
        f = self.submit_form()
        f.validates()
        line = port.readline()
        if line:
            data = float(line)
            humidity = relativeHumidity(line, 25)
            return render.base(f, humidity)
        else:
            return render.base(f, "Not valid data")

    def POST(self):
        f = self.submit_form()
        f.validates()
        temperature = f['Temperature'].value
        line = port.readline()
        if line:
            data = float(line)
            humidity = relativeHumidity(line, float(temperature))
            return render.base(f, humidity)
        else:
            return render.base(f, "Not valid data")


def relativeHumidity(data, temperature):
    volt = float(data) / 1024 * 5.0
    sensorRH = 161.0 * volt / 5.0 - 25.0
    trueRH = sensorRH / (1.0546 - 0.0026 * temperature)
    return trueRH


if __name__() == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I see that data is not being used in lines 25 and 37 and I have no idea why that is. If anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that you're attempting to use a wrong COM port.

Try running one of these one-liners in the console to figure out on what port the Arduino is:

```sh
python -m serial.tools.list_ports
python -c "from serial.tools.list_ports import comports; print(comports())"
```

This is a bit of a long shot since you're saying that you managed to talk with the Arduino via the Arduino Serial Monitor, so you must have already figured out that it is on `COM4`. But perhaps you disconnected/reconnected it in the meantime, and it ended up on a different port?

If the above one-liners work for you, you can incorporate this into your code, e.g. by displaying available devices to the user and asking them to pick one:

```py
com_ports = {i: port for i, port in enumerate(comports())}
print("+------------------------")
print("| Choose a serial port from the below list.")
print("+------------------------")
print("| Available serial ports:")
print("+------------------------")
for i, port in com_ports.items():
    print("| {}: {}".format(i, port))
print("+------------------------")
choice = input("  Port: ")

conn = serial.Serial(com_ports[int(choice)].device, BAUD_RATE)
...
```

You can also try making the program automatically find the Arduino by enumerating all available devices and checking their metadata. See [the docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo) for available fields.

Comment: I am quite certain I am using the correct COM as I checked the device manager and it is the only COM being used.